# System.Web.HttpCompileException (0x80004005)

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

My .net 4 intranet application works fine almost all the time. Sometimes, without making any change, it starts giving 500 exceptions with the following message:

```
System.Web.HttpCompileException (0x80004005): External component has thrown an exception. 
at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile() 
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() 
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath) 
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) 
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) 
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) 
at System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.LoadControl(VirtualPath virtualPath)
```

The only solution is the stop the inet service, delete C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net..\Temporary files and then everything starts working again.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: You can also try recycling the application pool in IIS. Just had an instance where the error went away after recycling the apppool.

Answer (score 2):

Try to clean temp asp.net files in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files`

Comment: That is exactly what I do, but I have to do it manually. Is there any way to make .NET to autoclean itself when this exception occurs?

Comment: i think this is a bug of Visual Studio, that is why you need write to Microsoft Technet.

Comment: @JorgitoGutierrez; did you figure out the root cause of your problem? I'm having an issue myself, and I cannot live with performing an IISreset now and then to take care of an unknown. The not acceptable part of this is that it happens without any change to the environment or the code, so I am very interested in finding the root of this issue.

Comment: @sonstabo No, i didn't not. However, I move my site to a new server (Windows 2008 x86 -- the former was x64) and the exception didn't happen anymore

Comment: Has anybody got a solution to this? I'm having the same error on a ASP.Net 4 shared hosting site and I do not have access to C:\windows\micro... folder. I tries moving the app to a different folder (to generate new temp files) but that did not solve the problem.

Comment: Arjun, you can contact with hosting support

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to clean the Asp.Net Temporary files or recycle the IIS pool.

Read more on [Microsoft support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3118750)

Comment: i did it it help for few hours then the issue comes back

Comment: @Yazan-Ati : Comment suggest to recycle the iis pool, while support link is for updating framework version. Is it the correct link provided?

Comment: this is not a solution, it's a workaround..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in a .NET 4.8 ASP.NET application running in Azure WebApps. Source of it was an `OutOfMemory` exception during compilation performed by either `csc.exe` or `VBCSCompiler.exe`:

> Application: csc.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.OutOfMemoryException at...

> Application: VBCSCompiler.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.OutOfMemoryException at...

I found these exceptions in Event Log. In case of Azure WebApps it can be accessed from debug console in Kudu under LogFiles folder or directly from this url:

```
https://[yourAzureWebAppName].scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/eventlog.xml
```

When looking at memory usage graphs of WebApps in Azure portal there were indeed short spikes to 90+% of RAM usage. They were caused by either multiple deployments at the same time or Azure moving my apps to new VM. Both of these events caused the need for multiple applications recompilation.

Interestingly I also have same application sets running on many Azure VMs and I never had the issue there.