# mvc4 error External component has thrown an exception on compile

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, compiler-errors

I am getting an annoying error on my production website which is of type  System.Web.HttpCompileException . The way it works is like this, I make changes to a controller then a compile the production website so that the changes can take effect. That works however sometimes randomly when I navigate the website a System.Web.HttpCompileException pops up this normally occurs for up to 48 hours after a compile then it clears up which I don't think it's normal. What could be causing this error? oh and it has a tendency to occur more often if a webpage has a partialview. This is some additional information that I uncover with error details.. any suggestions would be great . Oh and this is the same issue as

[System.Web.HttpCompileException (0x80004005)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16058526/system-web-httpcompileexception-0x80004005)

System.Web.HttpCompileException: External component 
has thrown an exception.

```
 System.Web.HttpCompileException (0x80004005): External component has  thrown an exception.
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.PostProcessFoundBuildResult(BuildResult result, Boolean keyFromVPP, VirtualPath virtualPath)
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetBuildResultFromCacheInternal(String cacheKey, Boolean keyFromVPP, VirtualPath virtualPath, Int64 hashCode, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
 at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultFromCacheInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
 at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
 at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
 at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType(VirtualPath virtualPath)
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType(String virtualPath)
   at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerWrapper.System.Web.Mvc.IBuildManager.GetCompiledType(String virtualPath)
   at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
  at System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.RenderPartialInternal(String partialViewName, ViewDataDictionary viewData, Object model, TextWriter writer, ViewEngineCollection viewEngineCollection)
  at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
  at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName)
  at ASP._Page_Views_account_panel_cshtml.Execute() in e:\hostingspaces\myines\example.com\wwwroot\Views\Account\panel.cshtml:line 43
  at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
  at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
  at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage()
  at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
  at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
  at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
   at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
  at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<>c__DisplayClass28.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19()
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1b(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to clean the Asp.Net Temporary files or recycle the IIS pool.

Answer (score -1):

**Restart my computer did the trick!**