# Asp.Net MVC How to prevent HttpCompileException exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

In our production server there are sometimes an exception that occurs suddenly:

> *Error: System.Web.HttpCompileException (0x80004005): External component has thrown an exception*

The solution is to clean the Asp.Net Temporary files or recycle the IIS pool.

But we don't know the reason for this exception, so that we can't prevent it happens in the future again and again, and this exception occurs one time in month approximately.

What could be the reason for it? And what is a good solution to handle it?

Comment: There might be memory problem. Try to keep eye on memory  Consumption of app.

Comment: This might be useful to look at it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16058526/system-web-httpcompileexception-0x80004005

And also this one : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723.aspx

Comment: @kizilsu I saw it before, not much help. There is no comment that sais how to prevent it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve these issues by upgrading to the .NET Framework 4.6.1

Alternatively, You can uninstall updates 3098779 and 3097997 if you have upgraded your system to the .NET Framework 4.6 or have installed Visual Studio 2015 from a fully updated .NET 4.5.1 or 4.5.2 system that has updates 3098779 and 3097997 installed.

Comment: What do you mean when you said upgrade to 4.6.1? Do you mean target your projects to 4.6.1 or just upgrade .net framework on machine to 4.6.1.